# How write a periodic number as a fraction?

Tags: number-theory

What I call as a periodic number is for exemple

$$0.\underbrace{13}_{period}131313...$$ or   $$42.\underbrace{465768}_{period}465768465768.$$

So how can we put theses numbers like a integer fractional, i.e. of the form $\frac{a}{b}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: yes, sorry. I corrected it.

Comment: Use the geometric series.

Comment: Call the first one $x$. What is $100x$? What is $13+x$?

Comment: Shift the decimal point by as many digits as the period length is (multiplying by a power of 10) and subtract both numbers.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the suggested one, I have voted to reopen.

Comment: This question asks for a method for converting a repeating decimal to a ratio of integers. The linked question asks for a proof that such a ratio exists. While on the face of it that does not actually request the _method_ for finding such a ratio, in fact the obvious answer to the linked question is to demonstrate the method, and that's what the answers did; hence answers to this question are already posted on the linked question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To illustrate the method lets take 0.13131313131313131313... as an example

Let $x = 0.13131313131313131313...$

We now multiply by a suitable power of 10 such that the fractional part is the same. In this case 100

$100x = 13.13131313131313131313... = 13 + x$

Thus $99x = 13 \Rightarrow x = \dfrac{13}{99}$

For your second example you need to multiply by a bigger power of 10 but the method is identical.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the existing answers, note that if your number isn't quite in the right form, you can get it that way easily; so if you want to know about $N=1.02371717171\cdots$, you can write $$1000N=1023+ 0.717171\cdots$$

Apply the method mentioned in the other answers to write the repeating part as a fraction $$1000N=1023 +\frac ab$$ then isolate $N$ again: $$N=\frac{1023}{1000}+\frac a{1000b}$$

Now you will need to combine as indicated to get a single fraction, but that's easy.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying your number by a suitable power of $10$ we can make some parts the nummber jump to the left of the decimal point leaving *identical* fractional part. That is $10^mx$ and $x$ have the same fractional part. SO their difference is an integer $a$: That is $a= (10^k-1)x$, this shows $x$ is a rational number.